# Get 'lang' attribute from HTML tag using XPath

Tags: php, html, curl, xpath, attributes

I'm trying to get the value of the 'lang' attribute in a HTML tag (fetched using cURL, which is all going well). Super cleaned up HTML shown below:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

When I use:

```
// Get HTML tag
$html = $xpath->query('//html');

echo '<pre>'. print_r($html, true) .'</pre>';

// Does a HTML tag exist at all?
if($html->length == 0) {
    $htmlUsed = false;
}

// If HTML tag exists get value
if($html->length > 0) {
    foreach($html as $tag) {
    echo '<pre>'. print_r($tag->attributes, true) .'</pre>';

        foreach($tag->attributes as $attribute) {
            echo $attribute;
        }
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
DOMNodeList Object
(
    [length] => 1
)

DOMNamedNodeMap Object
(
    [length] => 0
)
```

> How do I get the value of this attribute in the HTML element? It is present in the $response of the cURL that is fetching the page (on which I perform the XPath query). Note: $tag->getAttribute('lang') doesn't return the desired result, because $tag->attributes appears to be empty.

Comment: `$html->item(0)->attributes->item(0)->nodeValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$html = $xpath->query('//html');
echo '<pre>'. print_r($html, true) .'</pre>';
// Does a HTML tag exist at all?
if($html->length == 0) {
    $htmlUsed = false;
}
// If HTML tag exists get value
if($html->length > 0) {
    foreach($html as $tag) {
        echo $tag->getAttribute('lang');
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> DOMNodeList Object
> (
>     [length] => 1
> )
> ```
>
> en

Comment: Making it 'work' like this has shown me that the problem lay elsewhere. I was doing loadHTML on $response (including CURLOPT_HEADER, true) and have now switched to doing loadHTML($body) which doesn't contain any headers. Problem: solved!